# Will this setup do the trick?

Tags: gear, ableton-live

I'd like to start making electronic, instrumental music on my PC.

Being a bit of a newbie in terms of the technical aspects involved, I've done quite a bit of reading, but I'm still not quite sure about everything before I start shelling out money for the soft- and hardware.

- DAW: Ableton Live Suite
- Akai MPD 218 Drum Pad Controller
- Akai APC 40 Mk2 Ableton Controller
- Nektar Impact IX 49 Master Keyboard

My question is simple and probably also stupid: 
Is that a good choice of equipment for a beginner, am I missing anything really important, do these things work together flawlessly? Do you see any caveats? Your thoughts please. :)

Thank you very much!

Edit: I've incorrectly called the drum pad Akai APD 218, but MPD 218 is correct.

Comment: I have to put in a shout out to Ableton Push (or Push 2) instead of the Akai controllers if you haven't already considered it.

Comment: @Todd Wilcox: I will have to take a look at it on Youtube. Thanks for mentioning!

Answer (score 1):

Everything you've chosen is a good choice (quality speaking).
Now it really depends on the use you have of these products and what kind of musical/sound activity your trying to pursue.

Comment: I will only use software synths, FX and sample(r)s. Will be trying to make downtempo music influenced by trip-hop and jazz. No plans on performing live. Thanks for your input, appreciate it.

Comment: So, yep, it seems a good choice :) . Your welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather invest in a better Midi-keyboard than in Pad Controller. Since 4 years of producing i didn't use my pads productive.
Also i would recommend you to buy a good USB-Audiointerface.

For example:
Keyboard: M-Audio Code 49
Audiointerface: Focusrite Saffire 6 USB

But it depends on what you like to use when you are producing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's very good to hear what experienced people think. Would you still recommend an audio interface even if it's not used to connect external inputs like microphones, but only for connecting monitoring headphones?

Comment: Yes, the DAC (Digital to Analog Converter) of your onboard soundcard is to slow to calculate some VST-Synthesizer in real-time. If you are interrested: [link](http://blog.dubspot.com/understanding-audio-interfaces/)

Comment: And I made the experience that limiting your equip lets you get more creative.